LDA over time in R
I'm trying to apply LDA over a large sample of documents. My dataset is the speeches given by Yellen and Powell taken from this website
My code looks like this
library(topicmodels)
library(tidytext)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(quanteda)
library(tm)
library(lsa)
library(lubridate)
bis_speeches=read.csv("central_bank_speeches.csv")
bis_speeches=bis_speeches[,c("date", "description","text", "author")]
authors=c("Janet L Yellen", "Jerome H Powell")
PY_speeches=bis_speeches[bis_speeches$author %in% authors,]
PY_speeches$date=as.Date(PY_speeches$date)
positions=c("Vice Chair", "CEO", "President", "Member")
PY_speeches <- PY_speeches[!grepl(paste(positions, collapse = "|"), PY_speeches$description), ]
PY_speeches$date_month=substr(PY_speeches$date, 1,7)

PY_speeches_list=split(PY_speeches$text, PY_speeches$date_month)

PY_speeches_list=as.list(PY_speeches_list)

speeches_monthly_corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(PY_speeches_list))
speeches_monthly_corpus <- tm_map(speeches_monthly_corpus, tolower)
speeches_monthly_corpus <- tm_map(speeches_monthly_corpus, removePunctuation)
speeches_monthly_corpus <- tm_map(speeches_monthly_corpus, function(x) removeWords(x, stopwords("english")))
speeches_monthly_corpus <- tm_map(speeches_monthly_corpus, stemDocument, language = "english")
speeches_monthly_matrix=DocumentTermMatrix(speeches_monthly_corpus, control = list(minWordLength=5, maxWordLength=12))

speeches_lda_results=LDA(speeches_monthly_matrix, k=50, method="Gibbs",control=list( seed=141096)) 

Now the thing is that these speeches have a time component to them, and I'd to know if there's a way for me to get time variation in the topics without having to run LDA over each speech (or a subset of speeches)
Also, please note that the csv I read is the one I download from the link posted

Hi JF96. It sounds like these are two independent analyses. You've created a 50 topic model, and now want to perform some time series analysis, looking for changes in topic abundance over time. You can use broom::augment() to add your LDA model topics back to the original data.

thanks! would you mind telling me how to do that?

You might want to look up  Structural Topic Modeling
